# values on y-axis cut short when making horizontal barchart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm making a horizontal barchart with words on the y-axis and integers on the x-axis. The problem is that some of the words is so long that its cut off in the saved picture. When I type out the chart in the console it looks nice, but not when I saved it and try to open it from the folder.

I've been playing around with imagesize but to no avail

```
    antal = []
    i=0
    for i in range(10):
        antal.append(int(new_object_list[i].count))
        i +=1


    ord_lista = []
    j = 0
    for j in range(10):
        ord_lista.append(str(new_object_list[j].word))
        j +=1

    y_pos = np.arange(len(ord_lista))
    plt.barh(y_pos, antal)
    plt.yticks(y_pos, ord_lista)


    plt.savefig("Barchart.png")
    im = Image.open("Barchart.png")
    bg = Image.new("RGB", im.size, (300,300,300))
    bg.paste(im,im)
    bg.save(r"Barchart1.gif")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subplots_adjust()` to add additional spacing, so to add more space to the left hand side, you could do the following:

```
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=0.3)
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ord_lista = ["long", "longer", "even longer", "even longer still"]
n = len(ord_lista)
values =  np.random.rand(n)
plt.barh(np.arange(n), values, align='center', fc='#80d0f1', ec='w')
plt.yticks(np.arange(n), ord_lista)
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=0.25)
plt.show()
```

Would give you:

[image: matplotlib demo plot]